# Media Attachments are creating draft posts

Tags: wordpress

On our dev site, I'm experiencing issues with WordPress and how it's suddenly handling Media Attachments.  When I upload Media (such as an image) inside a post, it's creating another Post (as a Draft) that simply references that media.  Also, any changes to that piece of Media (in the Media Library) results in another Post.

For example, let's say I am writing a post about Mark Twain.  If I add an image of Tom Sawyer and Huck Finn, it will add it to the post fine.  No problem.  The issue is when I go back to the Posts Dashboard, I'll see Draft Posts called Huck_Finn & Tom_Sawyer.  These will be empty, uncategorized drafts without any content.  It also appears to create a new post whenever I modify that piece of Media in the library.  For example, if I were to have renamed Huck_Finn and Tom_Sawyer to Huck Finn and Tom Sawyer, I'd see the following in the Posts Dashboard:  Huck_Finn, Tom_Sawyer, Huck Finn, Tom Sawyer.

Comment: More information:  When I upload the image via the Media Library (not via the Media Library inside a new post) - this issue doesn't occur.

Comment: I started deactivating plugins and it looks like it was a problem that was caused by the Content Audit plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-audit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started deactivating plugins and it looks like it was a problem that was caused by the Content Audit plugin. wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-audit

Answer (score 0):

From looking at `wp-admin/includes/post.php - line 197`, the comment indicates that the parent was forced into existence (via a draft) because the attachment needs the parent to to have a valid id to associate with.